# Invocar un WebPanel gx como post y obtener un parámetro que trae el body

Tags: genexus

Buenos días,

estoy con un ambiente `Genexus` `.net` y tengo la siguiente situación.

Tengo un webpanel: **wp.aspx**

que recibirá datos de un sistema externo vía un `POST`
. Necesito obtener un dato (**strDato**) cuando invoquen a ese **wp.aspx** que vendrá en el `body`. Entonces estoy probando de la siguiente manera:

**wp.aspx** es así:

en las `rules`:

```
parm(in:&strDato)
```

en el form tengo la variable &strDato

```
Event Start

GuardoTXTLog.Call(&Pgmname+"#COMINEZO")
GuardoTXTLog.Call(&strDato)
GuardoTXTLog.Call(&Pgmname+"#FIN")

Endevent
```

estoy probando invocarlo via POST desde otro wp: llamador.aspx

en un botón de **llamador.aspx**  ejecuto esto:

```
&httpclient.Host = &serverHost.Trim()
&httpclient.Port = &serverPort
&httpclient.BaseUrl = &ServerBaseURLRest.Trim()
&httpclient.AddHeader(!'Content-type',!'application/json')

&body='{"strDato":"ACA ESTOY PROBANDO"}'
&httpclient.AddString(&body)

//&httpclient.AddVariable("SecurityToken",&body.Trim())     

&httpclient.Execute(!'POST', "wp.aspx")
&respuesta=&httpClient.ToString()
```

Gracias por la mano que puedan darme!
Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!

**wp.aspx** es el llamado así:

en las `rules`

```
parm(in:&strDato)
```

en el form tengo la variable &strDato

```
Event Start
    &Respuesta=&httprequest.ToString()
    GuardoTXTLog.Call(&Pgmname+"#COMINEZO")
    GuardoTXTLog.Call(&Respuesta)
    GuardoTXTLog.Call(&Pgmname+"#FIN")
Endevent
```

**llamador.aspx** es así: 
en un botón ejecuto esto

```
&httpclient.Host = &serverHost.Trim()
&httpclient.Port = &serverPort
&httpclient.BaseUrl = &ServerBaseURLRest.Trim()
&httpclient.AddHeader(!'Content-type',!'application/json')


&httpclient.AddVariable("strDato","ACA ESTOY PROBANDO") 

&httpclient.Execute(!'POST', "wp.aspx")
&respuesta=&httpClient.ToString()
```

Entonces en la variable `&Respuesta` obtengo el valor `&strDato` y a partir de allí uso genexus
Saludos,
Bruno